# Are Kaijus alien creatures or Earth based animals?

Tags: character, pacific-rim

As per the size of the Kaiju, they seemed like they could be monsters from Earth, but in the movie they showed that they may be alien too. So I just want to know, what exactly are these Kaijus?

Comment: And the definitions of what you call a *"monster"* or an *"alien"* would be...?

Comment: Dinosaur, we can call them monsters, but I don't think so we can call Alian to them.

Comment: A dinosaur is an animal, a werewolf for me would be a monster, a kaiju is some kind of alien monster. "Monster" is a pretty broad term, that's why I would have liked to hear your definition of it, as otherwise the question is pretty moot.

Comment: Do you mean if they are monsters originating from Earth or from outer space?

Comment: I just want to know, what kind of creature was that? An animal or an Alien. Don't make it so complicated please.

Comment: @SystemDown . Yes Sir

Comment: And sorry to say, but I dont think so you should put this question on hold, as per the question its "Are Kaijus Alien or Animal (monsters)"? And I dont find it unclear.

Comment: @NeeleshPandey - As you can see from our many questions your distinction is *not* clear. It doesn't matter if you find it clear (of course you do, you wrote it!), but if readers find it clear.

Comment: @SystemDown, now you made the question very simple to understand, that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Ah, the new question looks much more reasonable, even if easily answered by just watching the movie, though.

Comment: Hmm, You are right, so still it will be on hold?

Comment: @NeeleshPandey - Now people need to vote for it to be reopened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The Kaiju are a race of amphibious creatures genetically engineered by
>   the [Precursors](http://pacificrim.wikia.com/wiki/Precursors), a sentient race from the [Anteverse](http://pacificrim.wikia.com/wiki/Anteverse). In 2013, the
>   Precursors opened a portal between dimensions at the bottom of the
>   Pacific Ocean, allowing the Kaiju to enter Earth's dimension. (Source:[pacificrim.wikia.com](http://pacificrim.wikia.com/wiki/Kaiju))

So its clear from that, Kaiju  are the monster created by Alien scientists.